# SSH connection script from win10 to linux

Tags: linux, cmd

I need to connect to ServerB through the gatekeeper ( ServerA)
but I CANT get to serverB with my cmd script.

**Manual connection in cmd**

1. plink -v user@123.123.123.123(server A) -pw password
2. the terminal will display term=xterm
3. press enter to pass through
4. ssh 234.123.123.123 (server B)
5. enter a password
6. done

```
#!/bin/bash
plink  -v user@serverA -pw password ssh serverB
Pause
```

I hope the script can get me into **5.** and enter the password by myself

Comment: Does `plink  -v user@serverA -pw password uname` allow you to bypass the `term` prompt, and just run the command, then disconnect? If not, can you figure out what causes it to be printed?

Comment: It stay at term=xterm without disconnect. I can manual press enter to get through

Comment: Disabling or figuring oot how to bypass that prompt would be the best fix, but probably not a good fit for Stack Overflow. As a workaround, you could perhaps use an Expect script, but I don't know if that exists for Windows.